# What do I do when Yahoo asks for my cell number but I don’t have one?

Tags: account-management, yahoo-mail, yahoo

I was making a Yahoo account so I can email my teacher my assignment, and then it asked for my cell number. I'm 16 year old and I don't have a cellphone. I won’t see my teacher for 3 weeks because we’re on break. How can I bypass this?

Comment: I made some edits to your question to make it easier for people to answer and understand. You can use services other than Yahoo you know, especially if it is just to send an email.

Comment: There are _temporary sms phone numbers_, but if they discontinue the service and you got locked out of your account, that would be bad.

Answer (score 1):

It's a measure to make it harder for spammers to create throwaway accounts. Unfortunately, like many security measures, it inconveniences innocent users more than the bad guys it's trying to stop.

There are *lots* of free webmail services out there. Certainly there's some that won't bug you for a cell phone number. (Have a look at [Computers: Internet: E-mail: Free: Web-Based](http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Internet/E-mail/Free/Web-Based/) for some, or perhaps even http://alternativeto.net/software/yahoo-mail).